# How to handle orientation change in fragment in viewpager programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments,only one of them must change his orientation(but not activity), activiy has flag `congifChanges="orientation|screenSize"`, and `viewPager`. I want to change layouts programmatically on every orientation change.

I already have two different layouts, if I will scroll pages on viewPager, layout will change as expected.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the layout XMLs in `layout` and `layout-land` folders?

Comment: @Lamorak, Yes, i have, orientation changes only if we go on alarms page and return on statistics, i.e. after recreating fragment

Comment: Yeah, the orientation change event gets consumed by the activity so it does not rotate. What you need is to handle the event manually and make the fragment recreate. In your activity override `onConfigurationChanged()` method and try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Comment: @Lamorak I haven't adapter there

Comment: whad do you have in your viewpager then?

Comment: @Lamorak
pagerAdapter in MainActivity, i tried notifyDataSetChanged(), not help, data not changed, in this fragment i have only two custom view without any adapters or any system classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always in such situations, it seems that the decision should be difficult to implement. In fact, it was three lines:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) getView();
    viewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    View view = onCreateView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), viewGroup, null); viewGroup.addView(view);
}
```

[Here](http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/how-to-change-fragment-layout-on-orientation-change/) where I found it

Redrawing the fragment is not the best idea if it keeps some data (plays video, map, etc.) because I have no dynamically changing data there, and I had to show the same thing, only in a different orientation, I used this approach if you need to change the orientation and did not lose the data you must read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject).

Comment: Good solution but, it could cause memory leak! At least it caused in my app, 0.07M increase memory usage every time when orientation changes...

Comment: @Ademİlhan
In my case I have a small memory leak 0,02MB per 1-3 second, started position at 13MB, but when orientation changes GC do his work and  allocated memory back to 13MB. But it has nothing to do with this fragment. I removed these lines, but result is still the same, all I can advice is some tools. [One](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), [two](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), [nice article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/fixing-memory-leaks-android-studio-albert-lai). Good luck!